# Are cookies sent with image requests?

Tags: image, cookies, request

If I have a site (e.g. foo.com) and on the home page of foo.com, there is an image request where the src=bar.com..., will the cookies on the bar.com domain be sent to the bar.com servers?

Answer (score 34):

Yes. HTTP doesn't distinguish between one kind of resource or another (image vs html).

Comment: Which is why ad servers like doubleclick, etc can track you across the web.

Comment: I've used this fact to set cross-domain login cookies. Not even close to reliable (just because the user may not wait for your image to load), but it definitely works.

Comment: @ojrac: Wikipedia (etc.) use images for cross-domain login too, BTW.

Comment: Technically this is correct, but Firefox and Safari block 3rd party cookies by default, and many adblockers do as well, and many users change their settings to block 3rd party cookies, so the answer in practice is that this cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 18):

The cookie will typically be included in any type of request, but the scenario you describe is what's known as a *third-party cookie* (that is, the cookie is set on a domain that is different than the domain of the loaded page) and most browsers offer a privacy setting to block third-party cookies.

A third-party cookie allows the owners of bar.com to place an image (say a banner ad) on foo.com and track the users of foo.com even though those users have never visited bar.com.  This is a privacy concern and many users elect to block such cookies.

Comment: And how might you block those cookies?

Comment: @EliTheHuman -- it's typically a browser setting. For example, in Chrome, under Settings -> Advanced -> Site Settings -> Cookies and Site Data, there's a toggle for "Block Third-Party Cookies".

Comment: But is there a way to block cookies that other websites put on your site, if you use their image per se?

Comment: @EliTheHuman -- no, there isn't. When you include an image or other content from another site, the request for that image goes directly from the user's web browser to that other site, so that site can send cookies to that browser. To prevent that, you'd have to either download the image and upload to your own site, or else proxy the request for the image. (That is, you could set up your own site that the browser would send the request to, and then on your server you'd send the request to the other site, and you'd pass the resulting response back to the browser, without any cookies.)

Answer (score 16):

This question is old, but was the first result on Google for me, so I think it's worth clarifying how this works nowadays (2021).

When bar.com sets the cookie, they can specify a `SameSite` attribute.

If the cookie is set with **SameSite=Lax** (or the SameSite attribute is not specified), then the cookie **will not be sent for requests for images**/iframes/etc hosted on bar.com, but **will** be sent if the user clicks a link on your foo.com homepage that takes them to bar.com

If the cookie is set with **SameSite=Strict**, the cookie **will not** be included in requests to bar.com that originate from another webiste, including if the user clicks a bar.com link on foo.com.

If the cookie is set with **SameSite=None**, the cookie **will** be sent to bar.com, including requests for images.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question; the answer is yes they will by default. Why would you not want to receive cookies from a third party if they’re you’re own cookies you put on the user? I feel like there’s got to be a reason to do what you’re saying but I think it’s unrelated to the security/tracking loophole they’re asking about.

Comment: The answer is that it depends on what settings bar.com used when setting the cookie. It isn't up to the owner of foo.com at all.

Comment: Exactly, I think this is why linking images are unsupported by many sites — bar.com gets specific user traffic on foo.com, not just generic server requests for the image

Answer (score 5):

If third-party-cookies are not blocked by the user then most modern browsers will set or send cookies of the third party domain when a request is made to the third party web site. IE 6 has a different kind of blocking mechanism called leashing. wiki: A leashed cookie is a third-party cookie that is sent by the browser only when accessing a third-party document via the same first-party.

Answer (score 2):

Yes cookies are sent on all requests.
This includes "img" and "script" as well as XMLHttpRquest calls from javascript and can be a security issue on script tags as scripts loaded by one website can load scripts from another site and will send their authentication cookies too. This can be exploited to steal data.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a subject of CORS protection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `aspx/js/css/image` requestion need the cookie verification.