# Image requests are sent with cookies set by other domains after enabling CORS via Rack CORS Middleware. How to stop it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, cors

I am using [Rack CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem to enable cross origin request for my Rails app. When there is an image request to my app, I can see that it has "Cookie" header attached along with it which has cookie data set by other domains (Eg: Google Analytics). I don't want this header data. How to stop sending this header in the request?

Below is by config code in application.rb,

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Does :headers => :any has something to do with this?

I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019370/are-cookies-sent-with-image-requests) . But have no idea how to block third party cookies. Help is much appreciated.