# Cookie is sent in every request?

Tags: html, web, cookies

Assume I have an HTML page named ABC, host in **https://fakehost.net/abc.html**. And in its content, there is an image XYZ with src = '**[https://fakehost.net/imgs/xyz.png**'](https://fakehost.net/imgs/xyz.png**%27)

The host uses cookies so in the first time I visit that host (**fakehost.net**), the server send me cookies. And after that, every request to that host, the cookies will be attached.

When I visit **abc.html**, it internally send 2 requests, one for **abc.html** and another one for the image. The first one will attach cookies, I'm sure.

But how about the second one? The request to get the image? Is cookies attached?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are cookies sent with image requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019370/are-cookies-sent-with-image-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this yourself by visiting to the Network tab of the developer console. Check the request headers of the image requests and you will see that the cookie headers are sent.

And the answer is - yes. Cookies are sent in all the requests.

Here is more insight on this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019370/are-cookies-sent-with-image-requests#:~:text=Yes%20cookies%20are%20sent%20on,be%20exploited%20to%20steal%20data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019370/are-cookies-sent-with-image-requests#:%7E:text=Yes%20cookies%20are%20sent%20on,be%20exploited%20to%20steal%20data).